# Entity Framework 4 and Empty classes

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have a data entry form and it involves several tables to get inserted to. I bound the text property for each textbox to the relevant class property. As some fields are not mandatory I may end up with one of the classes having no data.
Will EF detect this and not insert it or will I have to check this manually before submiting changes?

Comment: You have a Post action or Submit button, right? What does that code look like?

Comment: I hadn't added one yet was just checking if I needed to implement checks before I wrote it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've created an instance of the entity and added it to the entity set, then the entity will be created on submitchanges(). It's your responsibility to add the corresponding constraints to the properties of the entities and check for empty inputs.

Comment: Ok I will add the checks in my submit button click handler. Thank you.